# 400 Bad Request Inserting an event in Google Calendar

Tags: google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I am using the Google Calendar API and I am trying to send a request to the API for inserting an event but I'm getting an error.

This is the request that I am sending:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/riteshmehandiratta%40gmail.com/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQwHy_3OYLmXtZpSa5PIwnBO3hqLWolMXpTYiFOEtjlEmbxNrYn
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{

 "end": {
  "date": "2/14/2007"
 },
 "start": {
  "date": "2/14/2007"
 },
 "kind": "calendar#event",
 "summary": "Hello World"
}
```

and the response I am getting is:

```
400 Bad Request

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  private, max-age=0
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  122
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Sat, 23 Mar 2013 17:36:22 GMT
expires:  Sat, 23 Mar 2013 17:36:22 GMT
server:  GSE

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "badRequest",
    "message": "Bad Request"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Bad Request"
 }
}
```

I am unable to figure out why I am getting a bad request error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i can tell your date format is wrong, the API docs indicate:

```
 The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.
```

You might want to use the 'Try it' form at the bottom of this page to first make sure your requests are valid:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#try-it

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did (PHP):

```
//Passed in a GET variable name of 'date'
//Tells parser the current format
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $_GET['date']);

//Adding the event start date, modifying the format to suit googles encoding
$start->setDate($df->format("Y-m-d"));
```

The script snippet above is working for me.

Rohan is correct about their formatting condition.